# Is it okay to use $scope.functionName or should I use var functionName = function() ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on an Angular App and in my controllers I have been using $scope to create my functions ex:

```
$scope.getJobs = function(){
 //code here
};
```

Should I use

```
var getJobs = function(){
// code here
};
```

instead?

I am still learning Javascript and Angular 1.x and would like to understand the best practices!

Comment: You haven't mentioned the context... Do you need to reference this function outside of the controller? Do you need to pass the function as an argument? You could just do `function getJobs() { /* code */ }`.

Comment: I honestly wasn't sure of the difference but I now, thanks to everyone's feedback, understand the $scope allows for the use of the function in the View and the normal function declaration is used just within the javascript files scope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.getJobs() is now available in `$scope` object and is accessible to your view.

```
$scope.getJobs = function(){
 //code here
};
```

This is a `private` function which you can use it in your `controller`, but won't be availble to your view.

```
var getJobs = function(){
// code here
};
```

The best case is if you want to use/call the function in your view, attach the function/variable to $scope else just go with plain old way of `function declaration or expression.`

**Note:** Angular triggers a `digest cycle` for checking on variables. Modifying a variable/function which you are not using in your view may cause extra digest cycles which can impact your performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using the `controllerAs` instead. That way you bind your controller do a specific object in the scope. Then you don't have to worry about overwriting that scope.

Bad:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{someVar}}
  <div ng-controller="myOtherCtrl">
    {{someVar}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Good:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as my">
  {{my.someVar}}
  <div ng-controller="myOtherCtrl as myOther">
    {{myOther.someVar}}
  </div>
</div>
```

For the controller code that would lead to not having to inject `$scope` for setting variables. Instead bind to the controllers `this`:

```
function myCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.getJobs = function() {...};
}
```

Read the https://johnpapa.net/angular-style-guide/ for more information on best practices :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

In case of a private function:

```
var getJobs = function(){
// code here
};
```

It wont be accessible from the View. This function will only be available for the controller.

And, in case you want to expose the function to the View, you must add the function to the $scope

```
$scope.getJobs = function(){
 //code here
};
```

In this case you will be able to to call it from the corresponding html file.

Comment: So if I want to do something like:

<button ng-click="getJobs()">Get Jobs</button>

Then I need to use $scope to allow the View to run that code?

Comment: exactly! That is the way to expose a function from the controller to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use ControllerAs syntax:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.variable= 'text';
    vm.getJobs = function() { };
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as MyCtrl">
    <div ng-click="MyCtrl.getJobs()">{{ MyCtrl.variable}}</div>
</div>
```

For more information on this best practice (and a lot of others), have a look at Jon Papa's styleguide:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to make the function accessible in your HTML template. Suppose you had a controller like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.myAlert = function(){
        window.alert('foo');
    };

    var myConsole = function(){
        console.log('bar');
    }
}]);
```

Then you could do this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="myAlert()"></div>
```

But you could not do this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="myConsole()"></div>
```

By making the myAlert function a property of $scope, it makes the function available to all of the elements within that $scope.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you use `controller` vs `controllerAs` syntax.

Let's assume you have this controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function() {

    $scope.alert = function(input) {
      alert(input);
    };    
});
```

If you use controller you have to add those functions to scope to be accessible from UI.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-click="alert('hello')"></div>
```

Now this will work nice and alert will show.

However if you use controllerAs syntax you can just use `this.` and add your methods to your `this` inside controller.

```
app.controller('MyController', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.alert = function(input) {
      alert(input);
    };    
});
```

Now in your html you have to use this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" ng-click="vm.alert('hello')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for best practices in general, John Papa's style guide is pretty much the holy grail of angular best practices. It addresses this question exactly as well. You should give it a read!

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md